# Class that extends rectangle won't overlap libgdx

Tags: java, libgdx

I am trying to delete bullet and enemy whet bullet overlaps enemy, but for some reason overlapping is not detected. I don't know how to help it.
as for me it suppose to work correctly

BULLET AND ENEMY CLASSES

```
private class Enemy extends Rectangle {
        public int health;
        public float x;
        public float y;
        public float speed;

        public Enemy (float x, float y, float speed, int health){
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        }
        public void updateCoor(){
            x +=speed*Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
            y = 100;//}
        }
    }

    private class Bullet extends Rectangle{
        public float x;
        public float y;
        public float speedX;
        public float speedY;

        public Bullet(float x, float y, float dirX, float dirY) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;

            int factor = 2;
            float dividerFactor = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
            speedX = factor*((dirX - x) / dividerFactor);
            speedY = factor*((dirY - y) / dividerFactor);
            System.out.println(TAG + " " + x + " " + y + " " + dirX + " " + dirY);
        }
        public void updateCoor(){
            x += speedX * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime() * 5000;
            y += speedY * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime() * 5000;
        }
    }

    SpriteBatch batch;
    Texture enemyImage,bulletImage;
    OrthographicCamera camera;
    Array<Enemy> enemies;
    Array<Bullet> bullets;
    long time;
    Vector2 vector2;
    Vector3 touchPos;
    int y;
    ShapeRenderer renderer;
    long lastEnemyTime;

    @Override
    public void create() {
        batch = new SpriteBatch();
        camera = new OrthographicCamera();

        camera.setToOrtho(false);

        enemyImage = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("enemy.png"));
        bulletImage = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("bullet.png"));
        time = TimeUtils.nanoTime();
        renderer = new ShapeRenderer();

        enemies = new Array<Enemy>();
        bullets = new Array<Bullet>();

        vector2 = new Vector2();
        touchPos = new Vector3();
       spawnEnemy();
        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(this);
    }
```

spawning enemy

```
    public void spawnEnemy() {
        Enemy enemy = new Enemy(0,20,10,2);
        lastEnemyTime =TimeUtils.nanoTime();
        enemy.height = 3;
        enemy.width = 6;
        enemy.speed = 100;
        enemies.add(enemy);
    }
```

spawn bullet

```
    public void spawnBullet(int screenX, int screenY) {
        Bullet bullet = new Bullet(Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/2, Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/3+40, screenX, screenY);
        bullet.height = 1;
        bullet.width = 1;
        bullets.add(bullet);
    }
    @Override
```

render

```
    public void render() {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 1, 0, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        camera.update();

        batch.begin();

        for (Bullet bullet : bullets) {
            batch.draw(bulletImage, bullet.x, bullet.y);
        }
        for (Enemy enemy: enemies){
            batch.draw(enemyImage,enemy.x,enemy.y);
        }

        batch.end();

        if (TimeUtils.nanoTime() - lastEnemyTime > 1000000000) {spawnEnemy();}

        Iterator<Enemy> iterator = enemies.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()){
            Enemy enemy = iterator.next();
            enemy.updateCoor();
        }
        Iterator<Bullet> iter = bullets.iterator();
        while (iter.hasNext()) {
            Bullet bullet = iter.next();
            bullet.updateCoor();

            if (iterator.hasNext()){
                Enemy enemy = iterator.next();
            if (bullet.overlaps(enemy)) {
                iter.remove();
                iterator.remove();
                System.out.println("sdla");
            }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
        spawnBullet(screenX, Gdx.graphics.getHeight() - screenY);
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Could you explain your code a bit more to point out where you think the problem lies. Which class is `Rectangle` which you extend?

Comment: it seems that enemy and bullet does not have width and height. that is why they din't want to overlap

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By declaring its own `x` and `y` floats, your Rectangle subclass hides the `x` and `y` fields of the Rectangle class, so you are never changing them. The `overlap` method is continuing to use the default x and y values of 0. Do not declare `x` and `y` in your subclass.

Comment: Good point, I would actually anticipate the `overlaps` method to always return `true` because of this.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to tell without seeing it run, but there are two potential problems I would first check...

---

The first thing I would check out is your coordinate system. Take a look at your width and height, compared to how you draw.

```
enemy.height = 3;
enemy.width = 6;

bullet.height = 1;
bullet.width = 1;

batch.draw(enemyImage,enemy.x,enemy.y);
batch.draw(bulletImage, bullet.x, bullet.y);
```

I'm not sure how large (in pixels) your actual images are - but its very possible that they are not matching your width and height. So while the *images* might be overlapping, its possible the *rectangles* are actually not overlapping. Without any other context, I would assume `width` and `height` are *pixel* sizes - so they are very small right now.

It would be easy to check this by either drawing the Rectangle on top of the image, or drawing the image to be the width/height of the rectangle, but I know for myself it would be very challenging to find a one-pixel bullet on my screen.

---

The second thing I would check, if your rectangles are seeming to pass through each other, try slowing them way down and see if it still happens.

You could be encountering a problem where the bullet and enemy are "teleporting" through each other.

For example: `I` moves down 2 spots per update, `O` moves right 2 spots per update

```
X X X I X -> X X X X X -> X X X X X
X X X X X    X X X X X    X X X X X
X X X X X    X X X I X    X X X X X
O X X X X    X X O X X    X X X X O //No Collision! "teleported" past each other
X X X X X -> X X X X X -> X X X I X
```

The normal way to fix this is to create an imaginary line between where you were, and where you are going to be, and see if that intersects any imaginary line from another object.